# Tensorflow: How to create a Pascal VOC style image

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation

I'm working on implementing a semantic segmentation network in Tensorflow, and I'm trying to figure out how to write out summary images of the labels during training. I want to encode the images in a similar style to the [class segmentation annotations](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/segexamples/index.html) used in the Pascal VOC dataset.

For example, let's assume I have a network that trains on a batch size of 1 with 4 classes. The networks final predictions have shape `[1, 3, 3, 4]`

Essentially I want to take the output predictions and run it through `argmin` to get a tensor containing the most likely class at each point in the output:

```
[[[0, 1, 3], 
  [2, 0, 1],
  [3, 1, 2]]]
```

The annotated images use a color palette of 255 colors to encode labels. I have a tensor containing all the color triples:

```
  [[  0,   0,   0],
   [128,   0,   0],
   [  0, 128,   0],
   [128, 128,   0],
   [  0,   0, 128],
   ...
   [224, 224, 192]]
```

How could I obtain a tensor of shape `[1, 3, 3, 3]` (a single 3x3 color image) that indexes into the color palette using the values obtained from `argmin`?

```
[[palette[0], palette[1], palette[3]],
 [palette[2], palette[0], palette[1]],
 [palette[3], palette[1], palette[2]]]
```

I could easily wrap some numpy and PIL code in `tf.py_func` but I'm wondering if there is a pure Tensorflow way of obtaining this result.

EDIT:
For those curious, this is the solution I got using just numpy. It works quite well, but I still dislike the use of `tf.py_func`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


def voc_colormap(N=256):
    bitget = lambda val, idx: ((val & (1 << idx)) != 0)

    cmap = np.zeros((N, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(N):
        r = g = b = 0
        c = i
        for j in range(8):
            r |= (bitget(c, 0) << 7 - j)
            g |= (bitget(c, 1) << 7 - j)
            b |= (bitget(c, 2) << 7 - j)
            c >>= 3

        cmap[i, :] = [r, g, b]
    return cmap


VOC_COLORMAP = voc_colormap()


def grayscale_to_voc(input, name="grayscale_to_voc"):
    return tf.py_func(grayscale_to_voc_impl, [input], tf.uint8, stateful=False, name=name)


def grayscale_to_voc_impl(input):
    return np.squeeze(VOC_COLORMAP[input])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tf.gather_nd()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd), but you will need to modify the shapes of the palette and logits to obtain the desired image, for example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as Image

# We can load the palette from some random image in the PASCAL VOC dataset
palette = Image.open('.../VOC2012/SegmentationClass/2007_000032.png').getpalette()

# We build a random logits tensor of the requested size
batch_size = 1
height = width = 3
num_classes = 4
np.random.seed(1234)
logits = np.random.random_sample((batch_size, height, width, num_classes))
logits_argmax = np.argmax(logits, axis=3)  # shape = (1, 3, 3)
# array([[[3, 3, 0],
#         [1, 3, 1],
#         [0, 2, 0]]])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
image = tf.gather_nd(
    params=tf.reshape(palette, [-1, 3]),  # reshaped from list to RGB
    indices=tf.reshape(logits_argmax, [batch_size, -1, 1]))
image = tf.cast(tf.reshape(image, [batch_size, height, width, 3]), tf.uint8)
sess.run(image)
# array([[[[128, 128,   0],
#          [128, 128,   0],
#          [  0,   0,   0]],
#         [[128,   0,   0],
#          [128, 128,   0],
#          [128,   0,   0]],
#         [[  0,   0,   0],
#           [  0, 128,   0],
#           [  0,   0,   0]]]], dtype=uint8)
```

The resulting tensor can be directly fed to a [tf.summary.image()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image), but depending on your implementation you should upsample it before the summary.