# How to create the labeled images in PASCAL VOC 12 as the ground truth?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, image-segmentation

I want to implement a semantic segmentation network and train it with PASCAL VOC 12. The ground truth is encoded into the colors instead of the labels and I am looking for the method to convert it into the labels. Also, I have read the below link:

[Tensorflow: How to create a Pascal VOC style image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959364/tensorflow-how-to-create-a-pascal-voc-style-image)

Is there any other more user friend code or algorithm to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem with PASCAL VOC dataset. Then I checked the function [deeplab/datasets/remove_gt_colormap.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/datasets/remove_gt_colormap.py) in the TensorFlow code in Deeplab for loading and converting the segmentation labels.

```py
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

def _remove_colormap_deeplab(filename):
  """Removes the color map from the annotation.

  Args:
    filename: Ground truth annotation filename.

  Returns:
    Annotation without the color map.
  """
  return np.array(Image.open(filename))

def _save_annotation_deeplab(annotation, filename):
  """Saves the annotation as png file.

  Args:
    annotation: Segmentation annotation.
    filename: Output filename.
  """
  pil_image = Image.fromarray(annotation.astype(dtype=np.uint8))
  with tf.gfile.Open(filename, mode='w') as f:
      pil_image.save(f, 'PNG')
```

To my understanding (**but not 100% sure**), `np.array(Image.open(filename))` will convert the Pillow Image object to a numpy array based on the loaded Pillow Image object's [mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes). Here I checked that the loaded Pascal VOC label/class image, for example, `datasets/pascal_voc_seg/VOCdevkit/VOC2012/SegmentationClass/2011_003078.png`, has the mode **P: palette** (meaning 8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a color palette). So due to the `'P' mode`, converting this PIL Image object into a numpy array, will map every pixel value into an index (i.e., corresponding to the `class or label` defined in PASCAL VOC) into the palette array of 256 RGB values.

You can also check my [jupyter note](https://github.com/ccj5351/studynotes/blob/master/segmentation/PASCAL_VOC_2012_Label_Colormap.ipynb) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In PASCAL VOC 12 there are 21 classes - 20 objects and 1 background. The classes are coded as pixel values. For example, the pixels belonging to background have values `0`. The rest of the classes are coded from `1` to `20` in alphabetical order. For example, the class `aeroplane` has pixel values equal to `1`. In each image you may have multiple classes. So, if you want to get the class labels, just read the corresponding groundtruth image using OpenCV or PIL and find the different pixel values present in the image. The pixel values will give you the object classes present in the image. In any image there will not be more than 3 or 4 different classes. However, there can be multiple instances of the same class.

Comment: Thank you so much, but still there is no clarification that how I can change the palette to the indices of the classes via a provided code.

Comment: Hello Harsh, the png image has 3 channel, so in your case aeroplane pixels (x,y,0) - (x,y,1) - (x,y,2) are all of them equal to 1? But in the Ground Truth every image has very different color. can u explain ? thanx  in advance

Comment: The label image is a single-channel 8-bit paletted image. In an 8-bit paletted image every pixel value is an index into an array of 256 RGB values. The color palette in PASCAL VOC is chosen such that adjacent values map to very different colors in order to make classes more easily distinguishable during visual inspection.

Comment: I think the official Matlab code (which can be found in the [PASCAL VOC devkit](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/index.html#devkit) ) can help us convert from RGB colors to labels. I also find a Python version at [here](https://gist.github.com/wllhf/a4533e0adebe57e3ed06d4b50c8419ae). I change the colormap visualization function to show the colormap via a 2-D array format. Please check the [code](https://gist.github.com/ccj5351/ae554ea70cef79ab1efdb3f9f92d2b37) and the [result](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uwH4H7jkVbllLQUeHmrNfNJYTp1kF0rd).

Answer (score 0):

It is a combination of @Harsh 's and @ccj5351's. VOC2012 labels are embedded into the image meaning all you have to do is read them in and identify the pixel values. It could be as simple as using `np.unique(img)` which will return the unique values in the array. If, say, it returns 4 unique values, then there are 4 classes (including background). You would also have to remove the colormap first. Have a look at [Tensorflow's approach](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/datasets/remove_gt_colormap.py), it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [this post](https://github.com/meetshah1995/pytorch-semseg/blob/801fb200547caa5b0d91b8dde56b837da029f746/ptsemseg/loader/pascal_voc_loader.py#L108). It simply creates a mapper between the colormap and indexes. It starts with background (first row) and goes over all the 20 classes (other rows).

[encode_segmap()](https://github.com/meetshah1995/pytorch-semseg/blob/801fb200547caa5b0d91b8dde56b837da029f746/ptsemseg/loader/pascal_voc_loader.py#L140) there does it for you.